# Find text in files and than move those files into new location

Tags: bash

```
grep -r "<text>" /path | ?
```

How do I pipe all related files into a new directory (location)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To copy all matching files to a directory you can write:

```
grep -rl "<text>" /path  | xargs cp -t /path/to/destination
```